# PreparedStatement with hashmap

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I am a newbie to Java, My problem is I am trying to insert currency rates into my MySQL database table called currency which contains two columns Currency_name and rate. The program fetches currency rate from finance yahoo API, I am facing The problem of storing the data into my database.

```
void checkRateAllAtEnd() throws Exception {
       /** print message  */
    System.out.println("checkRateAllAtEnd :");
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        List<Callable<HashMap>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<HashMap>>();
        for (final String ccy : CURRENCY) {
                tasks.add(new Callable<HashMap>() {
                        public HashMap call() throws Exception {
                                return getRates(ccy);
                        }
                });
        }
        ExecutorService executorPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        final List<Future<HashMap>> listRates = executorPool.invokeAll(tasks, 3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        for (Future<HashMap> rate : listRates) {
                HashMap ccyRate = rate.get();
                System.out.println("Value of £1 in " + ccyRate.get("CCY") + " is " + ccyRate.get("RATE"));
        }
```

I am lacking the credit to pass the values from hashmap to preparedStatement.

```
        String sql="update currency set currency_name='"+Value1+"'";
        preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
        preparedstatement.execute();
```

I have the entire class here on this link fully functioning to keep the question clean >>[linke](http://pastebin.com/HGtQ3qqW)<<<

this is the output of the programe which i would like to store into MYSQL Ideally i would like to store

> ccyRate.get("CCY") and  ccyRate.get("RATE")

```
checkRateAllAtEnd :
Value of £1 in AED is 5.9201
Value of £1 in AFN is 82.4359
Value of £1 in ALL is 171.681
Value of £1 in AMD is 650.4296
Value of £1 in ANG is 2.8849
Value of £1 in AOA is 154.4766
Value of £1 in ARS is 7.9438
Value of £1 in AUD is 1.5345
```

Comment: It helps to state exactly what the problem you are having is.

Comment: Expecting other to crawl through that is a bit impolite, create a small self-contained example and tell us some details about the error you're getting.

Comment: addCurrency will not return your preparedStatement, java is pass by value in the case it is passing the value of the reference(which is null) it will not pass back the created preparedStatement. Either move your preparedStatement handling into addCurrency or create the statement in  your main class. You will need to close the statement prior to closing the connection as well.

Comment: I thought so that it might be too much, I am not getting any errors I can connect and insert values to the table statically  _addCurrency(connection, preparedstatement,"USD" ,"1.602");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your addCurrency method is wrong - Not only you're not gaining anything by providing the  preparedStatmenet as parameter , you're not gaining anything when trying to close it, 
 as it is null at that point. 
Please show us the exact error/exception you're having and I'll edit my answer accordingly.